# Find value in multidimensional array by another key and value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```php
$array = array(
   'item-img-list' => array(
      array(
         'image-type' => 1,
         'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
      ),
      array(
         'image-type' => 2,
         'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
      ),
      array(
         'image-type' => 3,
         'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
      )
   )
)
```

How to get first 'image-url' value where 'image-type' = '2'?
I'm trying do that by this code but nothing:

```php
$zdjecia = $item['item-img-list'];
foreach($zdjecia as $zdjecie) {
   foreach($zdjecie as $key=>$value) {
      if($key == "image-type" && $value == "2") {
         $zdjecie_aukcji = $key['image-url'];
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

Works!

```
$searchKey = 2;
foreach($zdjecia as $zdjecie) {
    if (**$zdjecie->{'image-type'}** == $searchKey){
        $zdjecie_aukcji = **$zdjecie->{'image-url'}**;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use For Loop..! Set i and j in for loop.

Comment: i think `$zdjecia = $item['item-img-list'];` must be changed to `$zdjecia = $array['item-img-list'];`..If so everything is working for me

Comment: Try my custom function example, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$zdjecia = $item['item-img-list'];
$searchKey = 2;
foreach($zdjecia as $zdjecie) {
    if ($zdjecie['image-type'] == $searchKey)
        $zdjecie_aukcji = $zdjecie['image-url'];
        break;
    }
}
```

or (PHP >=5.5)

```
$zdjecia = $item['item-img-list'];
$searchKey = 2;
$results = array_column(
    $zdjecia,
    'image-url',
    'image-type'
);

$zdjecie_aukcji = $results[$searchKey];
```

Comment: Call to undefined function  array_column()

Comment: @Rafal - array_column() is only available in PHP >=5.5 as my answer says, though there is a repo on [github](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) that provides array_column() for earlier versions of PHP

Comment: Thank you! I had to change $zdjecie['image-type'] to $zdjecie->{'image-type'} and $zdjecie['image-url'] to $zdjecie->{'image-url'}

Answer (score 2):

modify to:

```php
$zdjecia = $array['item-img-list'];
foreach($zdjecia as $zdjecie) {
  if($zdjecie['image-type'] == '2') {
     $zdjecie_aukcji = $zdjecie['image-url'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A suggestions with custom function that I use for my project to find a value by key in multidimensional array:

```php
function array_search_multi($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();
    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array; 
        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, array_search_multi($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$results = array_search_multi($array, 'image-type', '2');
echo $results[0]['image-url'];
```

**Output:**

`http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...`

#### [Working example](http://ideone.com/mGPTiW)

Comment: Seems to be correct but i get empty array in print_r($results)

Comment: Do you have just empty array? It's not possible! I made new updated example for you? Maybe you saw the very first one? Did you see online example?

Answer (score 2):

Add `break;` right after

```php
$zdjecie_aukcji = $key['image-url'];
```

Answer (score 2):

why not simply this:-

```php
    $array = array(
       'item-img-list' => array(
          array(
             'image-type' => 1,
             'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
          ),
          array(
             'image-type' => 2,
             'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
          ),
          array(
             'image-type' => 3,
             'image-url' => 'http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...'
          )
       )
    );
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array['item-img-list'] as $k=>$v){
      $newArray[$v['image-type']] = $v['image-url'];
    }
```

Output :-

```
     Array
    (
        [1] => http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...
        [2] => http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...
        [3] => http://img07.allegroimg.pl/...
    )
```

or

```php
    echo $newArray[2];
```

you can also check key like this:

```
 if (array_key_exists(2, $newArray)) {
   // Do whatever you want
 }
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/BIk5B2)</kbd>

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Have u used `$array`?

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: There is not only one kind of [1] [2] [3]... There is many [1], [2] and [3] in array

Comment: @RafałKonarski : I have just suggested you based on your question. You have not mentioned anywhere in your question what your whole requirement. But what you have asked in your question you can achieve this by above code as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($zdjecia as $zdjecie) {
   foreach($zdjecie as $key=>$value) {
      if($key == "image-type" && $value == "2") {
         $zdjecie_aukcji = $zdjecie['image-url'];
      }
   }
}
```